# How can I combine those arrays into one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

Using this code I'm getting a lot of JSON objects inside different arrays:

[image]

Code:

```
for (let i=1; i<=150;i++){
fetch(`A valid URL ${i}`)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result.data.results))
}
```

How can I combine those arrays into one array?

Comment: take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it

Comment: Does it matter what *order* in which the elements are added to the array?  Or do you just want one big array with all elements and you can worry about potential sorting afterward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, you can push the results into another array:

```
let allResults = [];
for (let i=1; i<=150;i++){
fetch(`A valid URL ${i}`)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(result => 
allResults.push(...result.data.results))
}
```

However, you'd need to wait until all the `fetch` requests are finished, which you can do using async/await and Promise.all:

```
let allResults = [];
const promises = []
for (let i=1; i<=150;i++){
promises.push(fetch(`A valid URL ${i}`)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(result => 
allResults.push(...result.data.results)))
}
await Promise.all(promises)
```

If you do care about the order, then you need to return an array from the fetch request like so:

```
const promises = []
for (let i=1; i<=150;i++){
promises.push(fetch(`A valid URL ${i}`)
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(result => result.data.results))
}
const allResults = (await Promise.all(promises)).flat()
```

Comment: suggestion : use `.contact` to merge arrays rather than using `.push` + spread operator: `result => allResults.concat(result.data.results))`

Comment: `.concat` returns a new array though, in which case it's better to simply return the array and use `Promise.all` + `.flat()`

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
const items = Promise.all([...Array(150).keys()].map(i => fetch(`A valid URL ${i}`))).flat()
```